# Why am I getting a parsing error when trying to use a php namespace in my html document?

Tags: php, html

I am using a php namespace on my html page. I'm using Windows 8.  My code works perfict on my machine which is running WAMPSERVER 2.5.  I uploaded the files to my web site and got a parse error that says:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home/content/15/8677915/html/myDirectory/fileName.html on line 73
```

Line 73 has this line of code:  use myNamespace\UploadFile;

Here's the partial code that causes the error:

```
 <?php 
 use myNamespace\UploadFile;   <--------line 73

 require_once 'uploads/src/myNamespace/UploadFile.php';
 if (!isset($_SESSION['maxfiles'])) {
 $_SESSION['maxfiles'] = ini_get('max_file_uploads');
 $_SESSION['postmax'] = UploadFile::convertToBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
 $_SESSION['displaymax'] =      UploadFile::convertFromBytes($_SESSION['postmax']);

 }
 ....more code....
 ?>
```

I tried using escape like this: use myNamespace\UploadFile; but still the same error.  So I figured it may have something to do with UploadFile.php so I removed the line: use myNamespace\UploadFile; Then I got a another parse error.  This time it came from the UploadFile.php.  Here's what the error looks like:

```
 Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in     /home/content/15/8677915/html/dc-esports/uploads/src/myDirectory/UploadFile.php on line 2
```

Here's the code that is at the very top of the UploadFile.php file:

```
 <?php
 namespace westcoastchill;  <--------- line 2

 class UploadFile
 {
  protected $destination;
  protected $messages = array();
  protected $maxSize= 51200;
  .....more code here
 ?>
```

What is the parsing error here?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I'm using php version 5.2.12

Comment: The namespace feature was added in 5.3, thus your error. BTW, 5.2 and 5.3 are both EOL, you should update.

Comment: Yes that was my problem.  All went well when I upgraded to php 5.4.x.  Thanks!